# Bean request scope: No thread-bound request found on Spring Boot start

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, caching, spring-cache

I am trying to instantiate a simple cache that is request-scoped.

```
@Configuration
@EnableCaching
public class CacheConfiguration {

  @Bean
  @Scope(value = WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_REQUEST, proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
  public CacheManager requestCacheManager() {
    return new ConcurrentMapCacheManager("myValue");
  }
}

...

public interface MyRepository {

  @Cacheable(cacheNames = "myValue", cacheManager = "requestCacheManager")
  Integer getValue();

}
```

I expect that the application starts up correctly, however, it fails directly at start up, without any requests happening. I am not calling `MyRepository.getValue()` any outside of the scope of a controller.

```
2023-03-09 15:55:02.596 ERROR 13171 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.metrics.cache.CacheMetricsRegistrarConfiguration': Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.metrics.cache.CacheMetricsRegistrarConfiguration]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ScopeNotActiveException: Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.requestCacheManager': Scope 'request' is not active for the current thread; consider defining a scoped proxy for this bean if you intend to refer to it from a singleton; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:315)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:296)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1372)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:953)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:740)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:415)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1312)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1301)
    at tld.company.package.MyApplication.main(MyApplication.java:12)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.metrics.cache.CacheMetricsRegistrarConfiguration]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ScopeNotActiveException: Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.requestCacheManager': Scope 'request' is not active for the current thread; consider defining a scoped proxy for this bean if you intend to refer to it from a singleton; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:224)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:117)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:311)
    ... 22 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ScopeNotActiveException: Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.requestCacheManager': Scope 'request' is not active for the current thread; consider defining a scoped proxy for this bean if you intend to refer to it from a singleton; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:383)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
    at org.springframework.aop.target.SimpleBeanTargetSource.getTarget(SimpleBeanTargetSource.java:35)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:195)
    at jdk.proxy3/jdk.proxy3.$Proxy123.getCacheNames(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.metrics.cache.CacheMetricsRegistrarConfiguration.bindCacheManagerToRegistry(CacheMetricsRegistrarConfiguration.java:70)
    at java.base/java.util.LinkedHashMap.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:721)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.metrics.cache.CacheMetricsRegistrarConfiguration.bindCachesToRegistry(CacheMetricsRegistrarConfiguration.java:66)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.metrics.cache.CacheMetricsRegistrarConfiguration.<init>(CacheMetricsRegistrarConfiguration.java:57)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectConstructorHandleAccessor.newInstance(DirectConstructorHandleAccessor.java:67)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:211)
    ... 24 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.
    at org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes(RequestContextHolder.java:131)
    at org.springframework.web.context.request.AbstractRequestAttributesScope.get(AbstractRequestAttributesScope.java:42)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:371)
    ... 36 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Does annotating with @Lazy help here ?

Comment: Why do you want your caching (infrastructure) components and beans to be request scoped? Are you expecting the cache to be cleared (i.e. re-created) after each request? What is your UC? Setting the `CacheManageter` bean to request scope will not accomplish that, not unless the `CacheManager` provider implementation also implemented Spring's lifecycle interfaces. This would be a very expensive operation (recreating caches on each request) depending on the caching provider in use and not even practical in a distributed context using a client/server caching topology as is often the case.

Answer (score 0):

add like this in @Configuration class:

```
 @Bean(name = DispatcherServletAutoConfiguration. DEFAULT_DISPATCHER_SERVLET_BEAN_NAME)
    public DispatcherServlet dispatcherServlet (WebMvProperties webMvcProperties) {
        DispatcherServlet dispatcherServlet = new DispatcherServletO:
        dispatcherServlet.setDispatchOptionsRequest(webMvcProperties.isDispatchOptionsRequest());
        dispatcherServlet.setDispatchTraceRequest(webMvcProperties.isDispatchTraceRequest());
        dispatcherServlet.setThrowExceptionIfNoHandlerFound(webMvProperties.isThrowExceptionIfNoHandlerFound()); 
        dispatcherServlet.setPublishEvents(webMvcProperties.isPublishRequestHandledEvents());
        dispatcherServlet.setEnableLoggingRequestDetails(webMvcProperties.isLogRequestDetails());
        dispatcherServlet.setThreadContextInheritable(true);
        log. debug("init project dispatcher servlet")
        return dispatcherServlet;
    }


@Bean
    @ConditionalOnMissingBean({RequestContextListener.class, RequestContextFilter.class})
    @ConditionalOnMissingFilterBean(RequestContextFilter.class)
    public RequestContextFilter requestContextFilter() {
        OrderedRequestContextFilter orderedRequestContextFilter = new OrderedRequestContextFilter();
        orderedRequestContextFilter.setThreadContextInheritable(true);
        log.debug("init project request context filter!");
        return orderedRequestContextFilter;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

## TL;DR;

```java
@Bean(autowireCandidate = false)
@RequestScope
public CacheManager requestCacheManager() {
  return new ConcurrentMapCacheManager("myValue");
}
```

## Explanations

You are using spring boot and actuator, which comes with [CacheMetricsAutoConfiguration](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/0ca3ab7249437fcacdc7dbd3021896bc4c79c81b/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/metrics/cache/CacheMetricsAutoConfiguration.java#L37).
When autoconfiguration kicks in, [CacheMetricsRegistrarConfiguration](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/0ca3ab7249437fcacdc7dbd3021896bc4c79c81b/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/metrics/cache/CacheMetricsRegistrarConfiguration.java#LL53C4-L53C43) will be instanciated with

```java
Map<String, CacheManager> cacheManagers;
```

Spring will populate this map with all candidates of "CacheManager" available as dependency injection. Since our CacheManager is supposed to be request scope, it will fail on instantiation because CacheMetricsRegistrarConfiguration does not have a request context, which it can't never had.

That is also the reason why @Lazy is not helping here, the candidate are instantiated eagerly anyway by this autoconfigure.